# Trying to save to a plist when application terminates

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Ok so, I currently have a Master-Detail Application which has a tableview with a navigation controller, a detail view, and a modal view. The navigation view displays drink names, the detail view shows the selected drink details, and the modal view allows me to create a new drink or edit an existing one. Everything is populated from a plist which I already have moved to the documents directory and everything is reading from it just fine. I know this works because I have tested with an empty plist to see if my views change to blank, and they do successfully. All my views work perfectly. I can add edit and delete drinks and my table view updates with the new or deleted or changed drink. However it does not write to the plist file successfully (I am updating my plist from an array named "drinks" that is in my masterViewController). I think it is because I am trying to use this method below inside of my MasterViewController rather than in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DrinkDirections.plist"];

    [self.drinks writeToFile:writeableDBPath atomically:YES];
}
```

I have tested this by placing 2 NSLogs(): one in the applicationWillTerminate method that **I placed in** my masterViewController and one in the applicationWillTerminate method that is in my AppDelegate.m. The log only shows in the console from the one in the AppDelegate.m. So finally I can't figure out how to access my drinks array that is in my MasterViewController from my AppDelegate.m file so I can use the applicationWillTerminate method that is in my appDelegate.m to save to the plist. I will post my appDelegate.m code below which throws an error because the drinks property is in the MasterViewController.

AppDelegate.m (method)

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writeableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DrinkDirections.plist"];

    [self.drinks writeToFile:writeableDBPath atomically:YES]; //THIS LINE THROWS AN ERROR BECAUSE PROPERTY DRINKS IS ONLY ON MY MASTERVIEWCONTROLLER NOT MY AppDelegate

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, as mentioned by others here, `applicationDidEnterBackground:` is probably a better place to do this.  Secondly, your view controller isn't going to get this call all on it's own: it's a `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol call, and your view controller isn't one of those.

What you want to do is make your view controller receive the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification.  [The UIApplicationDelegate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) says:

> The application also posts a
>   UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification around the
>   same time it calls this method to give interested objects a chance to
>   respond to the transition.

So in your view controller you want to do something like this (warning: typed this code right into the webpage, didn't try to compile it):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register for notification.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                          selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) 
                              name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                            object:nil];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; 
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    // Do your plist saving here.
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do originally before I decided to try and send my array to my delegate file and use the method there. This worked perfectly for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

"For applications that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the application because the application simply moves to the background in that case"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

In short: your application is never "terminated" but put in background and killed while in background if necessary.

Since apps are "supporting" background by default, you should consider looking at:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: I tried to use the applicationDidEnterBackground: but again it is located in my AppDelegate.m file and I tried to implement this method into my MasterViewController.m but it would not work. I was going to try and use the method that is in my AppDelegate.m but i have the same problem that I did before. I don't know how to access my drinks array that is in my MasterViewController from my AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

You could also try saving the .plist when `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. According to apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html),

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is called instead of the applicationWillTerminate: method when the user quits an application that supports background execution. You should use this method to release shared resources, **save user data**, invalidate timers, and **store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later**. You should also disable updates to your application’s user interface and avoid using some types of shared system resources (such as the user’s contacts database). It is also imperative that you avoid using OpenGL ES in the background.

I highlighted the relevant portions. Hope this helps!